# Why ppoll() no wait my delay in Android Pie?

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel, embedded, gpio

I learned that the loop that checks the GPIO interrupt, which is supposed to loop at ~100 usec, is actually looping every 3 usec.  The reason is that the timespec I gave the GPIO event wait routine isn't working.  The wait instantly times out.

(Note that I removed extra code, error handling, and other features that are typical in a loop... like how to exit the loop)

```
struct timespec timeSpec = { 0, 100000 };  // sec, nanosec

struct gpiod_line_event event;
for (;;)
{

   result = gpiod_line_event_wait(pGpioLine, &timeSpec);    // ppoll(....timeSpec) is called inside this wait() 
   if (result > 0)
   {

      // GPIO IRQ detected
       if (gpiod_line_event_read(pGpioLine, &event) >= 0)

      {
         HandleIrq();

      }
   }
   else
   {
      //  100 usec timeout

      HandleTimeout()
   }

}
```

I tried to work around failure to properly wait by using many approaches. 
Adding a usleep(1); to the for loop doesn't work.  The actual sleep time is 30 to 40 msec which is too long for our driver.  This wasn't a surprise as this isn't a real time OS.

I tried changing the timeSpec to have an absolute instead of a relative time.  For example, I tried to create my own wait based on the REAL_TIME clock.

```
struct timespec timeToWait;

   clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &timeToWait);

   timeToWait.tv_nsec += 10000000UL;

    result = gpiod_line_event_wait(pGpioLine, &timeToWait);
```

This didn't work and I eventually concluded that the timespec is supposed to be relative for this gpiod API.  (The API is actually ppoll() )

Comment: The validity of `pGpioLine` is key here, but you have not included the code that assigns that or checks its validity.